# How do I build LLVM with ASAN?

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm

I want to build LLVM with ASAN. The docs state to use `LLVM_USE_SANITIZERS`. That didn't work. I've tried different combinations of flag, and wasted a lot of time searching but nothing. The last one I tried was:

```
cmake -G Ninja ../llvm \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/mikadore/local/llvm15-debug \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS='lld;clang;clang-tools-extra;compiler-rt' \
-DLLVM_USE_RUNTIMES='compiler-rt' \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBXML2=OFF \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_TERMINFO=OFF \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_LIBEDIT=OFF \
-DLLVM_ENABLE_ASSERTIONS=ON \
-DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER='Address;Undefined' \
-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ \
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=clang
```

I also copied `compiler-rt` from `llvm-project` into the `llvm` subfolder. But they all fail with the same error:

```
CMake Error at projects/compiler-rt/lib/gwp_asan/tests/CMakeLists.txt:61 (add_library):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:RTSanitizerCommon.x86_64>

  Objects of target "RTSanitizerCommon.x86_64" referenced but no such target
  exists.


CMake Error at projects/compiler-rt/lib/gwp_asan/tests/CMakeLists.txt:61 (add_library):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:RTSanitizerCommon.x86_64>

  Objects of target "RTSanitizerCommon.x86_64" referenced but no such target
  exists.


CMake Error at projects/compiler-rt/lib/gwp_asan/tests/CMakeLists.txt:61 (add_library):
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:RTSanitizerCommon.x86_64>

  Objects of target "RTSanitizerCommon.x86_64" referenced but no such target
  exists.


CMake Error at projects/compiler-rt/lib/gwp_asan/tests/CMakeLists.txt:61 (add_library):
  No SOURCES given to target: RTGwpAsanTest.x86_64
```

What is the proper way to build LLVM with ASAN enabled?

Comment: There is a typo in your cmdline: it should be `-DLLVM_USE_SANITIZERS=...` but you're having `-DLLVM_USE_SANITIZER`. Also, depending on your aims, I do not think you'd need compiler-rt.

Comment: @AntonKorobeynikov are you sure? It's `LLVM_USE_SANITIZER` in [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/1908820d6de5004964e85608070e7c869fc81eac/llvm/CMakeLists.txt#L653).

Answer (score 0):

The sanitizers, including ASAN, are indeed part of the compiler-rt project which contains sanitizer libraries, including sanitizer functions inserted into your code at compile time when the sanitizer is enabled (`__asan_` functions in case of using ASAN).

I was able to build LLVM 16 with ASAN enabled using CMake:

```
dir$ git clone https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
dir$ cd llvm-project
dir/llvm-project$ mkdir build && cd build
dir/llvm-project/build$ cmake -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;compiler-rt" ...
dir/llvm-project/build$ make -j ...
```